# Banner Google Ad not display - Ad failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config.)

Tags: flutter, ads

I get this error when use the banner test ad unit id : ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
in AndroidManifest.xml I use ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~4354546703 - the id of example project.

> Ad failed to load with error: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain:
> com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo:
> ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: ,
> adapterResponses: []))

But when I run the sample project which uses this id, it still works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that error because of my package name containing example.
After I changed it, it worked like a charm.

Comment: can you explain in brief? because I'm also facing this issue. I already tried so many things checks docs, codelab codes everything seems perfect but not even test ads working.

Comment: @TusharPatel It was like in my package name , It was ...example and after I changed it to a new name without example. Then this worked. Hope this can help you

Comment: thank you so much. The problem with the package name mine is com.anyname something after changes with com.anyname.anyname resolves the problem.

Comment: Yup, so glad to hear it.

Comment: Didn't work for me even after I change my package name